# android Screen Shows small screen when using libgdx orthographic camera

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, zooming, orthographic

```
public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        bird = new Bird(50, 300);
        cam.setToOrtho(false, GameMenu.WIDTH/2, GameMenu.HEIGHT/2); 
        bg = new Texture("bg.png");
    }



    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(bg, cam.position.x- (cam.viewportWidth/2), 0);
        sb.draw(bird.getTexture(), bird.getPosition().x, bird.getPosition().y);
        sb.end();
    }
```

**when adding  setProjectionMatrix and draw background image its shows small then my android screen**

**i am just started game programming using Libgdx framework**

i am already use these solutions but my project have not effect

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120722/screensize-vs-worldsize

Comment: You are not passing width and height to the draw() method so it defaults to drawing it at 1:1 image pixel to camera world unit ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have viewport? If yes try `sb.draw(bird.getTexture(), bird.getPosition().x, bird.getPosition().y, vievport.getWorldWidth(), viewport.getWorldHeight());`

Comment: I want set background image not bird sb.draw(bg, cam.position.x- (cam.viewportWidth/2), 0);.  and thank you for your answer

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. Just add `vievport.getWorldWidth(), viewport.getWorldHeight()` to bg draw.